# How to implement String comparator which considers "-" symbol after "z" letter

Tags: java, postgresql, sorting, special-characters

I have following code:

```
List<String> stringList  = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("VasyaPetrov");
stringList.add("Vasya_Petrov");
stringList.add("Vasyapetrov");

List<String> sortedCollection = stringList
        .stream()
        .sorted(String::compareToIgnoreCase)
        .collect((Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(sortedCollection);
```

the result is

```
[Vasya_Petrov, VasyaPetrov, Vasyapetrov]
```

So comparator considers `_` as symbol **before** any alphabetical letter.

Postgres `order by` considers `_` as symbol **after** any alphabetical letter

It is a root cause why my test is failed.

I want to make my test working.

1. **Is there any way change symbol code for concrete symbol in string comparator ?**
2. **Is there any way change symbol code for concrete symbol in postgres order by ?**

**P.S**. I see methods like `nullsFirst` in `Comparator` interface. I need smth like this but for "_"

Comment: Do you need a Java solution or a SQL (Postgres) solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually I want to have both of them

Comment: Did I understand right that you sort the data as part of your test setup, and then compare them with what you get from PostgreSQL? Then the solution may be not to sort the data, but provide them already sorted manually. A good practice is to avoid complex logic in test setup.

Comment: @Sergei Good point. I will keep this solution in mind

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you could create your own [RuleBasedCollator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html) with `_` symbol at the end and use it as a comparator, e.g. like this:

```java
String rules = "< a, A < b, B < c, C < d, D < e, E < f, F < g, G < h, H < i, I" +
        "< j, J < k, K < l, L < m, M < n, N < o, O < p, P < q, Q < r, R" +
        "< s, S < t, T < u, U < v, V < w, W < x, X < y, Y < z, Z < '_'";

RuleBasedCollator ruleBasedCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(rules);

List<String> stringList  = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("VasyaPetrov");
stringList.add("Vasya_Petrov");
stringList.add("Vasyapetrov");

List<String> sortedCollection = stringList
        .stream()
        .sorted(ruleBasedCollator::compare)
        .collect((Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(sortedCollection);
```

Then the result would be:

```
[Vasyapetrov, VasyaPetrov, Vasya_Petrov]
```

Comment: Interesting code, but it differs from default not only in replacement of '_ '